# Are these spaces zero-dimensional? What are some characterizations of zero-dimensional spaces?

Tags: general-topology, product-space, zero-dimensionality

**Disclaimer:** By a zero-dimensional space I mean a topological space having a base of sets that are at the same time open and closed in it.

At my university, we discussed zero-dimensionality and examples of zero-dimensional spaces.
I am asking whether the following spaces are zero-dimensional and how to, in general, find this about a space.

I only know that a subspace of zero-dimensional space is zero-dimensional and that for any compact topological space $X$, the notions of zero-dimensionality and strong zero-dimensionality coincide. Also, if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then $X$ iszero-dimensional if and only if it is totally disconnected.

But none of this seems to be very helpful, so I will appreciate any recommendations what to use.

**Question:** Are these space zero-dimensional?

1. $\omega \times \mathbb{R}$
2. $\omega \times \mathbb{R}^n$
3. $\omega \times S$ ($S$ = the circle $S^1$)
4. $\omega \times S_n$, $n > 1$
5. $R^n, n > 1$ (higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces)

I think the 5. is clear - because $\mathbb{R}$ is **not** zero-dimensional, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not zero-dimensional either (it is hereditary property).

For the rest - I am not really sure. If $\mathbb{R}$ is **not** zero-dimensional, does it imply anything about the product with other spaces?

Thank you for your advice or for any sources to read and find answers to this.

Comment: A product $A\times B$ contains always subspaces homeomorphic to $A$ and $B$, so...

Comment: What do you mean  by $\omega$? Do you mean $\omega_0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your spaces is zero-dimensional. $X\times Y$ is zero-dimensional iff both $X$ and $Y$ are (if both are non-empty). The factor spaces embed as subspaces in the product etc. And of course any connected space like $\Bbb R^n$, $S$ or $S_n$ is not zero-dimensional. The $\omega$ (as a discrete space) is, but that's not enough..